# JSON Schema: How to check every array item that has a specific value has the required properties?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

How can I check that for every array item, which has in the property `field1`the value `Value1`, the property `field2` is required?
If `field1` has another value than `Value1` then only `field1` is required.

Here is an example:

```
{
  "property_abc":[
    {
      "field1":"Value1",
      "field2": "Value2"
    },
    {
      "field1":"Value2"
    },
    {
      "field1":"Value3"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is my Schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "property_abc": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "field1": {
            "enum": [
              "Value1",
              "Value2",
              "Value3"
            ],
            "type": "string"
          },
          "field2": {
            "enum": [
              "Value1",
              "Value2",
              "Value3"
            ],
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "allOf": [
          {
            "if": {
              "properties": {
                "property_abc": {
                  "items": {
                    "properties": {
                      "field1": {
                        "const": "Value1"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "then": {
              "required": [
                "field1",
                "field2"
              ]
            },
            "else": {
              "required": [
                "field1"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "property_xyz": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  },
  "type": "object"
}
```

The above example is correct.

But the following one will throw an error, because for the first item in `property_abc` the property `field2` is required, but not existing:

```
{
  "property_abc":[
    {
      "field1":"Value1"
    },
    {
      "field1":"Value2"
    },
    {
      "field1":"Value3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `if` schema you have is looking in the wrong place - this schema applies to the object inside the array value of property_abc. I've pasted the correction below, and also moved it outside the `allOf` which serves no purpose here.

you might also have a look at the `dependencies` keyword, it might be helpful, but would take a bit of refactoring to express the constraints you have.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "property_abc": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "field1": {
            "enum": [
              "Value1",
              "Value2",
              "Value3"
            ],
            "type": "string"
          },
          "field2": {
            "enum": [
              "Value1",
              "Value2",
              "Value3"
            ],
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "if": {
          "properties": {
            "field1": {
              "const": "Value1"
            }
          }
        },
        "then": {
          "required": [
            "field1",
            "field2"
          ]
        },
        "else": {
          "required": [
            "field1"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "property_xyz": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  },
  "type": "object"
}
```

Comment: You saved my life.
I was over 4 hours trying to do this but to no avail.
Thanks.